# How to replace strings containing special characters in multiple files using bash?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a couple of txt files containing the string "[path]\". I want to remove them from all of those files using a batch operation. I searched and the command sed seems to be the way to do it but I do not know how to include the characters []\ in the syntax. What should I do?

Comment: I don't think you searched hard enough, searching for "sed special characters" should provide the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the characters that have special meaning to `sed`:

```
$ echo '[path]\' | sed 's;\[path\]\\;foobar;'
foobar
```

N.B. I used `;` as the separator character, to avoid [leaning toothpick syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome)

Answer (score 0):

You can escape any char by using the escape char `\`.

So something like this (say you're in vi):

```
echo '[path]\' | sed 's/\[path\]\\/path/g'
```

This will replace `[path]\` with just `path`

Comment: I think you have your /s and your \s mixed up

Comment: I'm fairly sure you're the one that has them mixed up.

Comment: So you are saying that `/` is the escape char? And that when the OP says they want to replace `[path]\ ` that the answer is a regex replacing `[path]/`? Really?

Comment: @JonathanWakely Please see my edits. I thought you were talking about the `/` as the argument separators for the sed.

Comment: Well now the answer isn't completely wrong, but saying how to do it with vi isn't entirely helpful when the question mentions batch operations and sed

Comment: You're a very picky man. :)